# A Javascript calculator code

Tags: javascript

I`m a very beginner in javascript but I need a code for a kind of calculator that add numbers as I click on buttons and display the total.

***Example:*** if I click the button 20, it should display the number 20 but after that , if I click button 5 it should display the total which is 25 and so on..

At the moment this is all that I was able to do:

```
<form name="Calc">
<input type="text" name="Numbers" size="16"><BR>
<input type="button" value="  5  " onClick="document.Calc.Numbers.value += '5'">
<input type="button" value="  10  " onClick="document.Calc.Numbers.value += '10'">
<input type="button" value="  20  " onClick="document.Calc.Numbers.value += '20'">
<input type="button" value="  30  " onClick="document.Calc.Numbers.value += '30'">
<input type="button" value="  50  " onClick="document.Calc.Numbers.value += '50'">
</form>
```

Comment: Don't add quotes around `'5'` etc.

Comment: What is your question then? You want a full working example?

Comment: @HuyLe: The above very nearly *is* a full working example. :-)

Comment: It doesn't work as I want. If I press 20 than 5, it should display the total but in my case appear 205 (instead 25)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main issues with what you have so far:

1. You've put your numbers in your `onClick` handlers in quotes (`'5'` rather than `5`). That means you end up doing *string concatenation* (adding a string to the end of another string) rather than addition.
2. The `value` property of form elements is always a string, which means even when you fix #1 above, you *still* do string concatenation (because JavaScript does string concatenation when you add a number to a string). So you have to parse the value in `Numbers` before adding to it. For your current simple project, you can do that by just putting a `+` in front of them, which coerces them to numbers:

   ```
   document.Calc.Numbers.value = +document.Calc.Numbers.value + theNumberToAdd
   ```

Here's an example with those two changes:

```html
<form name="Calc">
<input type="text" name="Numbers" size="16"><BR>
<input type="button" value="  5  " onClick="document.Calc.Numbers.value = +document.Calc.Numbers.value + 5;">
<input type="button" value="  10  " onClick="document.Calc.Numbers.value = +document.Calc.Numbers.value + 10;">
<input type="button" value="  20  " onClick="document.Calc.Numbers.value = +document.Calc.Numbers.value + 20;">
<input type="button" value="  30  " onClick="document.Calc.Numbers.value = +document.Calc.Numbers.value + 30;">
<input type="button" value="  50  " onClick="document.Calc.Numbers.value = document.Calc.Numbers.value 50;">
</form>
```

That said: This is not how I would recommend doing it. Instead, I'd:

1. Have my JavaScript code in a JavaScript file (or just a `script` block if you prefer it all in one file)
2. Have a JavaScript variable with your current value
3. Have a single click handler attached to the form that takes advantage of the fact that clicks "bubble" from descendant elements to their ancestors.

Like this:

```js
// A scoping function so we don't create global variables
(function() {
  // Our current value
  var value = 0;
  
  // Get our form
  var form = document.querySelector("form[name=Calc]");

  // Set the initial display of our value
  form.Numbers.value = value;
  
  // Add the click handler
  form.addEventListener(
    "click",
    clickHandler,
    false
  );

  // Handle clicks
  function clickHandler(event) {
    var amount;
    
    // Is the click on one of our inputs?
    if (event.target && event.target.tagName.toUpperCase() === "INPUT") {
      // Yes, get the input's value as a number
      amount = +event.target.value;
      
      // Add it to our amount
      value += amount;
      
      // Show the result
      form.Numbers.value = value;
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<form name="Calc">
<input type="text" name="Numbers" size="16"><BR>
<input type="button" value="  5  ">
<input type="button" value="  10  ">
<input type="button" value="  20  ">
<input type="button" value="  30  ">
<input type="button" value="  50  ">
</form>
```

That looks vebose, but that's mostly because of all the explanatory comments.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough example. You didn't provide any JavaScript so I added my own:

```js
window.Calc = {
  Numbers: {
    value: 0
  }
};

document.onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById('display').value = Calc.Numbers.value;
}
```

```html
<form name="Calc">
  <input id="display" type="text" name="Numbers" size="16">
  <BR>
  <input type="button" value="5"  onclick="window.Calc.Numbers.value  += 5"/>
  <input type="button" value="10" onclick="window.Calc.Numbers.value += 10"/>
  <input type="button" value="20" onclick="window.Calc.Numbers.value += 20"/>
  <input type="button" value="30" onclick="window.Calc.Numbers.value += 30"/>
  <input type="button" value="50" onclick="window.Calc.Numbers.value += 50"/>
</form>
```

---

### Why

JavaScript has Strings and Numbers. Strings can't be added. So when you take out the quotes, it should work fine.

---

### Alternative

I wouldn't recommend inline JavaScript, check out the demo, this makes it SUPER easy to add new numbers.

## [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blue1086/24uz024m/)